# Format Classification Report to Display Different Metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, report, artificial-intelligence, classification

So i have a Classification Report and i am currently making it display the overall Accuracy to two decimal places. I would like to change it to display Precision instead. However, is that even possible since it is technically displaying other Metrics including Precision already?

Current Code

```
print(classification_report(y_train, y_pred, target_names = target_names))
print('Accuracy {:.2f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_train, y_pred)))
```

I would like it to then become

```
print(classification_report(y_train, y_pred, target_names = target_names))
print('Accuracy {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_train, y_pred)))
```

When i try this i get errors. I already tried consulting the documentation on Sklearn, but i could not find anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? btw `classification_report` itself has the precision values.

Comment: It states 'NameError: name 'Precision_score' is not defined'. I was told by someone it is possible to switch it from Accuracy to Precision, but i cannot find info stating how. I just want to know if i can actually change the .format() to Precision from Accuracy.

Comment: have you imported `precision_score` from `sklearn.metrics`?

Comment: No. I will try it later today and see how it goes.

Comment: So i imported it and i trued to use it but i get this error 'ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].' So i guess i need to get the resolved and it should work.

Comment: Yep i got it working. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The resolution was to declare the following import

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score, precision_score
```

And then write this beneath my Classification Report and specify what type of result i wanted after reading this post:

[ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810062/valueerror-target-is-multiclass-but-average-binary-please-choose-another-ave)

```
print('TEXT: {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_train, y_pred, average='weighted')))
```