# Multilabel classification in scikit-learn with hyperparameter search: specifying averaging

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, hyperparameters

I am working on a simple multioutput classification problem and noticed this error showing up whenever running the below code:

```
ValueError: Target is multilabel-indicator but average='binary'. Please 
choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'].
```

I understand the problem it is referencing, i.e., when evaluating multilabel models one needs to explicitly set the type of averaging. Nevertheless, I am unable to figure out where this `average` argument should go to, since only `accuracy_score`, `precision_score`, `recall_score` built-in methods have this argument which I do not use explicitly in my code. Moreover, since I am doing a `RandomizedSearch`, I cannot just pass a `precision_score(average='micro')` to the `scoring` or `refit` arguments either, since `precision_score()` requires correct and true `y` labels to be passed. This is why [this former SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810062/valueerror-target-is-multiclass-but-average-binary-please-choose-another-ave) and [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269187/facing-valueerror-target-is-multiclass-but-average-binary?rq=1), both with a similar issue, didn't help.

My code with example data generation is as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X, Y = make_multilabel_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=2,
    n_classes=5,
    n_labels=2
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps = [
        ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('model', MultiOutputClassifier(MultinomialNB()))
    ]
)

search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator = pipe,
    param_distributions={'model__estimator__alpha': (0.01,1)},
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall'],
    refit = 'precision',
    cv = 5
).fit(X, Y)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

From the scikit-learn docs, I see that you can pass a callable that returns a dictionary where the keys are the metric names and the values are the metric scores. This means you can write your own scoring function, which has to take the estimator, `X_test`, and `y_test` as inputs. This in turn must compute y_pred and use that to compute the scores you want to use. This you can do doing the built-in methods. There, you can specify which keyword arguments should be used to compute the scores. In code that would look like

```py
def my_scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test) -> dict[str, float]:
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)
    return {
        'accuracy': accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),
        'precision': precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro'),
        'recall': recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro'),
    }

search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator = pipe,
    param_distributions={'model__estimator__alpha': (0.01,1)},
    scoring = my_scorer,
    refit = 'precision',
    cv = 5
).fit(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best example I could find on how to build my own scoring function.

Answer (score 0):

From [the table of scoring metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values), note `f1_micro`, `f1_macro`, etc., and the notes "suffixes apply as with ‘f1’" given for `precision` and `recall`.  So e.g.

```py
search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    ...
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision_micro', 'recall_macro'],
    ...
)
```